# Python- re.search() // Match start and end but do not include either in match result

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

My intention is to get all inbetween 'start' and 'end' variables.
Currently struggling to understand how to apply the filters to get group excluding the start and end criteria.

```
start = 'melons'
end = 'strawberry'
s = 'banana apples melons+cucumber+strawberry grapes'

r = re.search('', s)

print(r.group(1)) 
#print = +cucumber+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be achieved with below approach:

```
import re
start = 'melons'
end = 'strawberry'
s = 'banana apples melons+cucumber+strawberry grapes'

r = re.search(rf'{start}(.*?){end}', s)

print(r.group(1))
```

Output:

```
+cucumber+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting off with Regex, then I recommend you use [this](https://regex101.com/) tool. It's very useful and can help you write your own regex statements. It also will compile your statement to a language of your choice.

In the meantime, you can use a statement like `melons(.*)strawberry`:

```py
import re

regex = r"melons(.*)strawberry"

matches = re.search(regex, "banana apples melons+cucumber+strawberry grapes")

print(matches.groups()[0])
# +cucumber+
```

Comment: Thanks, i checked both answer and this is as good as with the exception of creating the parameter before hand. the use of rf'' allows me to add it to the string with minima effort.

Thanks for the tool it went a long way understanding how the pattern parameter functions.

Comment: No problem, hope I helped!